# Any easy to use php mysql datagrid?

Tags: php, mysql, datagridview

Anyone know of a FREE and easy to use PHP MySQL Datagrid class? I have used rGrid and Eyesis but need something like phpdatagrid. No requirement of AJAX features though. Just need basic features inbuilt like search by columns, pagination with page numbers(with jump to page dropdown), how many rows to show per page, multiple delete etc.

Just want to keep it simple and easy to use. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Eyesis grid, rGrid and phpmygrid are the most easy to use and implement free products available out there.
even jquery based solutions like datatabales.net and Flexgrid are quite awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind AJAX, ExtJS offers an excellent grid. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/paging.html
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty old question, but I wanted to add [MySqlGrid](http://www.mysqlgrid.com/) as a free/open-source solution to the OP's question. MySqlGrid will quickly create a fully functioning datagrid from **ANY** valid MySql select statement with very little effort. caveat: I wrote it!